# How to format code in posts on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, code-formatting

How to format code in posts on Stack Overflow? I am getting frequent error messages while submitting posts with code. I am getting the following message:

> Your Post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted  as
> code.Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
> or the ctrl+k keyboard shortcut.for more editing help , click the ?
> tool bar icon.

I have tried this by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> -->`enter code here` and entered the code but I am getting the same error message. Also, I have tried using ">" before every line, even then the same message appears.

Comment: Even here, this information is very searchable. For example, there are guidelines when writing your post with a link to more information.

Comment: There's a `?` icon at the top right of the box where you entered your question. Click it, then click "[advanced help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 4):

To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces:

```
This will be displayed in a monospaced font. The first four spaces
will be stripped off, but all other whitespace will be preserved.

Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks:
<i>This is not italic</i>, and [this is not a link](http://example.com)
```

To create not a block, but an inline code span, use backticks:

If you want to have a preformatted block within a list, indent by eight spaces:

1. This is normal text.
2. So is this, but now follows a code block:

   ```
    Skip a line and indent eight spaces.
    That's four spaces for the list
    and four to trigger the code block.
   ```

Comment: This is the most frustrating part of using StackOverflow for me.  For YEARS, I still cannot get this to work.  GitHub is so easy.  Why not use support GitHub markup.

Comment: [CommonMark code blocks](https://commonmark.org/help/tutorial/09-code.html) are now supported. I'm not sure since when.

Answer (score 2):

Highlight or select the code, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.